# SLF4 daily rolling logs

Tags: logging, slf4j

I am using simpleLogger for logging in my application. I want to have daily rolling logs ie I want to have a separate log file created for each day.

I have searched online but I have found ways of doing this using log4J and logback https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/ (Both are not used in this project)

I want to know if its possible to do this using SLF4 or I have to use another logging tool to achieve this.

Below is the simplelogger.properties file of the project

```
# SLF4J's SimpleLogger configuration file
# Simple implementation of Logger that sends all enabled log messages, for all defined loggers, to System.err.

# Default logging detail level for all instances of SimpleLogger.
# Must be one of ("trace", "debug", "info", "warn", or "error").
# If not specified, defaults to "info".
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info

# Logging detail level for a SimpleLogger instance named "xxxxx".
# Must be one of ("trace", "debug", "info", "warn", or "error").
# If not specified, the default logging detail level is used.    
#org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.xxxxx=

# Set to true if you want the current date and time to be included in output messages.
# Default is false, and will output the number of milliseconds elapsed since startup.
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true

# The date and time format to be used in the output messages.
# The pattern describing the date and time format is the same that is used in java.text.SimpleDateFormat.
# If the format is not specified or is invalid, the default format is used.
# The default format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS Z.
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS

# Set to true if you want to output the current thread name.
# Defaults to true.
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=false

# Set to true if you want the Logger instance name to be included in output messages.
# Defaults to true.
#org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true

# Set to true if you want the last component of the name to be included in output messages.
# Defaults to false.
#org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName=false

org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to have rolling files with slf4j simple logger.

Slf4j is a logging abstraction that you can include in your project by just including the api jar. You are free to use any logging implementation like log4j or logback. They both have predefined appenders that you can use. In fact simple logger is also a logging implementation that only logs to stdout.

To use simple logger, you would have included slf4j-api and slf4j-simple jars in your project. Replace the slf4j-simple jar with jars specific to log4j or logback implementation and place the log config file in the class path.

Read https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html to know the exact jar file you need to include.